# Flutter Unit Tests Timeout After setting "--platform chrome" In Linux

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

When running `flutter test --platform chrome` on Mac OS, all tests pass. However, on Linux (aws codebuild ubuntu), all tests timeout before being ran with the following error output:

```
{ "testID":1,
  "error":"TimeoutException after 0:12:00.000000: Test timed out after 12 minutes.",
  "stackTrace": "package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 334:28  
                 Invoker._handleError.<fn>\ndart:async/zone.dart 1383:47                      
                 _rootRun\ndart:async/zone.dart 1293:19                      
                 _CustomZone.run\npackage:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 332:10  
                 Invoker._handleError\npackage:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 288:9   
                 Invoker.heartbeat.<fn>.<fn>\ndart:async/zone.dart 1391:13                      
                 _rootRun\ndart:async/zone.dart 1293:19                      
                 _CustomZone.run\npackage:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 287:38  
                 Invoker.heartbeat.<fn>\ndart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart 18:15           
                 Timer._createTimer.<fn>\ndart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 398:19         
                 _Timer._runTimers\ndart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 429:5          
                 _Timer._handleMessage\ndart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 192:12
                 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage\n",
  "isFailure":false,
  "type":"error",
  "time":720026
}
```

**Why wont flutter "chrome" unit tests work in Linux??**

Answer (score 0):

**I found a workaround:**

1. Remove `--platform chrome` from the test command args.
2. Replace occurrences of `dart:html` and `dart:js` imports with:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'package:universal_html/js.dart' as js;
```